# Only allow 1-12 and 00-59 input in HTML / Javascript with regex and string replace

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace, regex-negation

To follow 12 hour time format I'm trying to replace the text in two input fields, one only allowing numbers from 1-12, and the other only allowing numbers from 00-59. So far I've been using javascript string replace, when not containing a regex pattern on an input event.

I've been experimenting with different negative lookahead variations (replace if not containing those values) of the regex below but with no luck

```
<input type="text" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/?!(1[0-2]|[1-9])/g, '');" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way might be to use [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) and match a digit from 1 -12 using [`^(?:1[0-2]|[1-9])$`](https://regex101.com/r/YNof8w/1)

If the value is not 1 - 12 then set it to an empty string.

```html
<form id="" name="">
  <input type="text" oninput="if (!/^(?:1[0-2]|[1-9])$/.test(this.value)) { this.value = '' }" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

A negative assertion in a regex is always "zero width"; that is, there is no specific part of the string which doesn't match.

To see why, consider the string "123" entered in the minutes field; clearly, it doesn't match the pattern /1[0-2]|[1-9]/, but which is the part that makes it not match? Is it the 3, leaving you 12? Or perhaps the 1, leaving you 23? Or perhaps the 2 and 3 should both be removed, leaving just 1?

Instead of making a negative assertion, the best approach in a case like this is probably to detect the part you want to keep, capture it, and then discard everything else. For instance, if you match `/^.*?(1[0-2]|[1-9])?.*?$/`, the entire string will always match, and the valid part (if it's there) will be in the capture variable $1; so you can replace the entire string with that captured part, effectively deleting the rest (the .*? at the beginning and end).